# pysftp -- paramiko SSHException, Bad host key from server

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, paramiko, pysftp

I'm trying to connect to a remote host via `pysftp`:

```
try:
    with pysftp.Connection(inventory[0], username='transit',
                           private_key='~/.ssh/id_rsa.sftp', port=8055) as sftp:
        sftp.put('/home/me/test.file')
except Exception, err:
    print sys.exc_info()
    print err
```

However, I get a weird exception raised that I can't find much detail on.

```
(<class 'paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException'>, SSHException('Bad host key from server',), <traceback object at 0x7fa76269c5a8>)
Bad host key from server
```

I found a related question that suggested I run `ssh-keygen -R [host]` to replace the key in my `known_hosts` file -- once I did that, I got a new error:

```
(<class 'paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException'>, SSHException('No hostkey for host abc.com found.',), <traceback object at 0x7f6b8520cb48>)
No hostkey for host abc.com found.
```

Now, if I try to ssh to this host, it prompts me again to trust the key to be put back into my `known_hosts` file, which I accept and can happily ssh onto the box. After this step, if I attempt to run my script again, I get the original error `Bad host key from server`.

Am I doing something wrong here?

*ninja edit*: I should mention that the following works fine from the terminal:

```
sftp -i .ssh/id_rsa.sftp -oPort=8055 user@host.com
sftp> put /home/me/test.file
```

Paramiko Debug Output:

```
[2016-07-14 10:32:23,809] | paramiko.transport - DEBUG - starting thread (client mode): 0x7f1dab10L
[2016-07-14 10:32:23,810] | paramiko.transport - DEBUG - Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_2.0.1
[2016-07-14 10:32:23,836] | paramiko.transport - DEBUG - Remote version/idstring: SSH-2.0-mod_sftp/0.9.9
[2016-07-14 10:32:23,836] | paramiko.transport - INFO - Connected (version 2.0, client mod_sftp/0.9.9)
[2016-07-14 10:32:23,837] | paramiko.transport - DEBUG - kex algos:[u'ecdh-sha2-nistp256', u'ecdh-sha2-nistp384', u'ecdh-sha2-nistp521', u'diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256', u'diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1', u'diffie-hellman-group14-sha1', u'diffie-hellman-group1-sha1', u'rsa1024-sha1'] server key:[u'ssh-rsa', u'ssh-dss'] client encrypt:[u'aes256-ctr', u'aes192-ctr', u'aes128-ctr', u'aes256-cbc', u'aes192-cbc', u'aes128-cbc', u'blowfish-ctr', u'blowfish-cbc', u'cast128-cbc', u'arcfour256', u'arcfour128', u'3des-ctr', u'3des-cbc'] server encrypt:[u'aes256-ctr', u'aes192-ctr', u'aes128-ctr', u'aes256-cbc', u'aes192-cbc', u'aes128-cbc', u'blowfish-ctr', u'blowfish-cbc', u'cast128-cbc', u'arcfour256', u'arcfour128', u'3des-ctr', u'3des-cbc'] client mac:[u'hmac-sha2-256', u'hmac-sha2-512', u'hmac-sha1', u'hmac-sha1-96', u'hmac-md5', u'hmac-md5-96', u'hmac-ripemd160', u'umac-64@openssh.com'] server mac:[u'hmac-sha2-256', u'hmac-sha2-512', u'hmac-sha1', u'hmac-sha1-96', u'hmac-md5', u'hmac-md5-96', u'hmac-ripemd160', u'umac-64@openssh.com'] client compress:[u'none'] server compress:[u'none'] client lang:[u''] server lang:[u''] kex follows?False
[2016-07-14 10:32:23,837] | paramiko.transport - DEBUG - Kex agreed: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
[2016-07-14 10:32:23,838] | paramiko.transport - DEBUG - Cipher agreed: aes128-ctr
[2016-07-14 10:32:23,838] | paramiko.transport - DEBUG - MAC agreed: hmac-sha2-256
[2016-07-14 10:32:23,838] | paramiko.transport - DEBUG - Compression agreed: none
[2016-07-14 10:32:23,935] | paramiko.transport - DEBUG - kex engine KexGroup1 specified hash_algo <built-in function openssl_sha1>
[2016-07-14 10:32:23,936] | paramiko.transport - DEBUG - Switch to new keys ...
[2016-07-14 10:32:23,952] | paramiko.transport - DEBUG - Bad host key from server
[2016-07-14 10:32:23,952] | paramiko.transport - DEBUG - Expected: ssh-rsa: '\x00\x00\x00\x07ssh-rsa\x00\x00\x00\x01#\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\xb9\x05\xddUF?o\xeet\xad\x06=\x83\xd6\xa8\xb1\x06\x03\xb7\xb5\xa5C\x80\x0c~\xa8\x83[w!\x16y\xe6@\xdajX\x90+c\xd4\x18X\xd7\xff\x05\x06\xe2\x19\x96\x8c&J\x0c\x1f\xd2\xefC\xa5\xc6\xbb\x1f\xc9N\xd7r\x12\xd29\x1f\xe1\xb6F\xe8\xdc(w~\x1f\xea\xea\xfdUT?^V\xe8=\'\xd60\xdc\xc44gYnn\xfe\xe8^?\x8b\xa8"\xda\xc7(\x18\xc3<\xa9\x1c\xa1)A3_\x00<$y\xbe\xd4$\xc2S\xe6\x93\xe3B^\xef\xe6\xbf\xb5\x88\xd6\x98EeP\x9aZm\xa7\xc5&\xffn\xc1lb\x1e[\x8d!*\xfa\xa3\xce\xb6\xe7\xd5U\r<E\xd2\xe1\x89.\xed%o\xefju\xde>=*b\xaeBO\xbf>\xe4/,\xd5@R\xc5\x9e\xac\xf5\x80\x04\xa9s)3\xb5\xbc\xc2\xcc\xe7\xa7\xb8\x04>uA\xb4O\xa6\xf3\xdb\x9c2\xb5"%n\x89\t\x8192\xe7#n\x82p\xee\xdf\x16]\xb3A\x93\xebm|\xb9\xd7\nXsmw\x81\xa9'
[2016-07-14 10:32:23,953] | paramiko.transport - DEBUG - Got     : ssh-rsa: "\x00\x00\x00\x07ssh-rsa\x00\x00\x00\x01#\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\xc6_\xea\xc1yF\xd5\xdd\x146\x8c\x0eU\xeah[3\x16VP\xde2\xbe~\xed\x92\xef\xb81\x14\xd8\xb7\xa7\x08\xa3\x02\xa8\n\x9f\x7f{\x896\x1b\x89/,\x92\x86\xc7M\xa5\x7f0Cj\xe6\x93\xb0\x0eup%\xa2p\x9d3i\xaco\xf7\x14\xfb\xfe\x8f}a\xcbJ :\xdf\xdd1\x10\xe8;\xd3%\x98k')\xf8\x1c\xc1D\x97\\\xcc\xe6\xf5*6\xc2\xf1\xb8\xcf!\xeed\x1co\xc1\x03\xb4v\xc0,?\xda\xc7\xa3\xd9\xe8\xafy\xf5k\xf7\xe8\xa1\x9cr\xfa\x81\xcd\xee\xd3\xeao\xa7\x072\xce\x8b\xf9\x95\x03\xa1\xe2\xaf\t\xa2\xba\xa1O\xbc\xbf}}\x9e\xc0t\x9bC\x88\xbd\x18'\x00?-\xa0\x05\x83I\x1ah#I\xfc\xebc$\xfc\xa0\xad\xeeP\x80\x88Bh_\xeb`\xb6\xab\x8bC\x83\x987\xba\x05\xb14\xea\x90\xac>\x99&\x99\xb3\xf9\nC\xdf\xfd\xba<\xf8\xaf\xca\xaf\xfa\x15+\x1e,L\xa1\xf0\x1e\xa5`\xbd>\xf4\xa63)\xae7F\xd2\xc9\xf2\xf3A\xa4\x10u\xa9"
(<class 'paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException'>, SSHException('Bad host key from server',), <traceback object at 0x7fb87f143ef0>)
Bad host key from server
[2016-07-14 10:32:24,037] | paramiko.transport - DEBUG - EOF in transport thread
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Workaround**
This seems to be some sort of bug with the `pysftp` wrapper... I'm not sure. Reverting to native `paramiko` got me connected just fine, so I'm going with that for now. Current working code:

```
rsa_key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file('~/.ssh/the_key', password='myPassword')
transport = paramiko.Transport((inventory[0],8055))
transport.connect(username='theUser', pkey=rsa_key)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
print sftp.listdir()
```

Comment: I do not think it's a bug in pysftp. It's rather that your `known_hosts` file contains a wrong host key. So pysftp fails, because the actual host key differs from the `known_hosts` file. Using `Transport` the way you do, you bypass the problem by completely avoiding the host key verification, what is a security flaw. Your code is susceptible to [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack). For a correct solution, see [Verify host key with pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38939454/850848) or the answers by @Erick and @Bohdan here.

Answer (score 4):

For me, once I had the host public key loaded in .ssh\known_hosts, the cookbook example worked.

But, I don't recall being prompted to ever save the host public key to my .ssh\known_hosts file.

[This link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/174692/what-are-the-risk-of-not-using-a-host-key-for-sftp-using-pysftp) is what helped me understand the host public key was separate from my own public/private key pair. I'm using exavault and they provide the public/private key pair, but did not provide the host public key.

I used ssh-keyscan using git bash for windows:

```
$ ssh-keyscan example.com
# example.com SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
example.com ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQAB...
```

and copied the key to my known_hosts file. Then it worked with pysftp 0.2.9.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem and for me the issue was in that host ssh key was changed, and my known_hosts file was containing the old one, so to fix it i've run:

```
ssh-keygen -f /Users/myUserName/.ssh/known_hosts -R myhost.com
```

Obviously you'll need to use path yo your known_hosts file and your hostname or IP.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is port based and it is a bug.

### First Option

I fixed it in a fork which you can find [over here](https://github.com/kristopolous/pysftp/commit/a3882bdbd59b6b5c06bde8f60a5c2af7847fa8e3). Essentially for ports other than 22 the query-language of host-lookup is done as such:

```
[host]:port
```

For instance, from the command-line:

```
$ ssh-keygen -H -F "[host]:port"
```

So that means use something like this in your `requirements.txt` if you want the patched version:

```
git+https://github.com/kristopolous/pysftp.git
```

---

### Second Option

If you want to just move on with life and not use this patch then there's another way.

Grab the keys you want via `ssh-keyscan` like so

```
$ ssh-keyscan -p port host > magical-known-hosts
```

Now if you open that up you'll see something like this:

```
$ cat magical-known-hosts
[host]:port ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAA...
[host]:port ssh-rsa AAAAA...
[host]:port ssh-ed25519 AAAA...
```

Well that's the syntax the library doesn't support so we swap that out.

```
$ sed -i 's/\[host\]:port/host/' magical-known-hosts
```

Now we are going to override an object in pysftp to use this file instead:

```
import pysftp
import paramiko

cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = paramiko.hostkeys.HostKeys('/path/to/magical-known-hosts')

with pysftp.Connection(host, cnopts=cnopts, port=port) as sftp:
  ...
```

And there you go. No need to pull down code from some random person on stack overflow if you don't want to. Feel free to use either solution.

Comment: To anyone else reading this; this should be the accepted answer if you are using a non-standard port.  I've read the change in the fork mentioned, and tried out the package.  thanks @kristopolous